# ionic2 or 3 implement three views with ion-split-pane?

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, splitpane

It works well with only one ion-split-pane.And I have two views in one page.

```html
<ion-split-pane>
  <ion-menu [content]="content">

    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Pages</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>

      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-avatar item-left>
            <img src="assets/img/avatar.jpg">
          </ion-avatar>
          <h2>Cher</h2>
          <p>Ugh. As if.</p>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>

    </ion-content>

  </ion-menu>

  <ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content main></ion-nav>

</ion-split-pane>
```

After that,I want to implement two side menus on the left through another ion-split-pane.I added the same code in the right view.It was black?!How to deal with the problem?

Comment: Provide [mcve] to get help.

Comment: It has updated,thanks for help!

Comment: Where is your `ion-split-pane` and what do you mean by two side-menus on left? Try to clarify your problem with a little more explanation.

Comment: I'm so sorry.I mean that it has three divided views in one page.Each of them has divided navigation.